# I am a begginer and I am trying to make a lottery sim just for fun and i dont know why but code does work

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, variables

```
number = input()

win = 1

if number == win:
    print("test")
```

I am trying to make it output something when number that i type in is the same as win number and even when i type 1 it still doesn't output anything. If this will help i am using Visual Studio Code version 1.52.1 and Python 3.9.1

Comment: `input()` returns a string, e.g. `'1'` and `win` is an integer (`1`), so they are not equal. In other words `'1' == 1` is `False`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think (and I'm a beginner too!) that the problem here might be that the 1s are two different types because user input defaults to string (in other words, it's character "1" rather than the integer one).  Try this:

```
number = input()

win = 1

if win == int(number):  # all I did here is force the input value to be an integer

    print("test")
```

Answer (score 1):

Type cast your input to an Int to compare

```
number = int(input())

win = 1

if number == win:
    print("test")
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the if `number` is an integer or `float` by doing `number = int(input)`. Then add an else statement, so if the number and winning number aren't the same, `print("fail")`.

Answer (score 1):

number = int(input('Enter your lottery number: ')) #this is to convert the input to an integer

win = 1

if number == win:
print('You won!')
else:
print('Better luck next time!')